# SimpleHtmlDom find td value

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Using Simplehtmldom, how would I access the values of both "file number" & "site address" in the rows below, assign them to variables .I have tried as many ways as I can think of, but just cant seem to crack it.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
 <table summary="Results of the Search" class="display_table" 
  cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="Row1">
    <td title="View Application Details" class="TableData">
      <a class="data_text" href="StdDetails.aspx?PT=Planning Applications On-Line&amp;TYPE=PL/PlanningPK.xml&amp;PARAM0=
                                    606013&amp;XSLT=
                                    /Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/EppingForest/xslt/PL/PLDetails.xslt&amp;FT=Planning Application Details&amp;PUBLIC=
                                    Y&amp;XMLSIDE=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/EppingForest/Menus/PL.xml&amp;DAURI=PLANNING
                                ">EPF/0480/18/NEW</a>
    </td>
    <td class="data_text" title="File Number">018049</td>
    <td class="data_text" title="Site Address">Hoggs Farm
Carters Green Road
Matching
Harlow
CM17 0NX</td>
    <td class="data_text" title="Development Description">Grade II listed building application for proposed extension</td>
    <td class="data_text" title="Status">NEW</td>
    <td class="data_text" title="Date Registered">--</td>
    <td class="data_text" title="Decision"></td>
  </tr>

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $html = str_get_html($output);

            $display_rows = $html->find('table[class=display_table]',0)->find('tr');  
            if(count($display_rows)>0)
                foreach($display_rows as $row)
                {
                    $tds = $row->find('td');
                    if(count($tds)==0)
                        continue;

                    $data = array();
                        foreach($tds as $td)
                    {

                               if($td->title=="File Number")
                        {
                           $filenumbertd = $td->children(1);
                    $filenumber= $filenumbertd;
                    echo $filenumber.'<br>';
                               }
                                }
                                 }
                planning_scrape( 1 );


        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: where do you want to extract the 'file number ' and 'site address' ? from the html <td> values of from the php you constructed.?

Comment: Hi Dean, From the <td> values.

Comment: are you adding your values manually from a form or from a database?

Comment: Dean, I am pulling the result set in from an online DB using Curl.The table of class="Display_Table" is returned.What I want to do is, using the library SimpleHtmlDom , put the values for the six  <td>'s in to variables and insert them in to a Mysql using PDO. So the value for title="Development Description" would go to $devdescription and so on etc.

Comment: use a valuable to echo the details using curl from your database and then use the same valuables to insert them in the database. follow the procedure of a form input.